# Android TextView Truncation Priority or Compression Resistance

Tags: android, xml, textview, truncation

I'm laying out 3 views horizontally on the screen (fixed-size image and 2 single-line text views: `leftTextView` and `rightTextView`) and I'm trying to get the `rightTextView` to hug against the `leftTextView`, but in the event that the width of both labels would exceed the screen size, truncate the `leftTextiew`.

Example of desired functionality:

```
|img|leftText|rightText|                ||(end of screen)
|img|leftTextMedium|rightText|          ||
|img|leftTextTooLongSoTrunc...|rightText||
```

What's actually happening:

```
|img|leftText|rightText|                ||(end of screen)
|img|leftTextPrettyLongButNotHuge|rightT||
|img|leftTextWhichIsIncrediblyLongBlahBl||
```

Currently, if the size of both text views exceeds the view's width, the `rightTextView` ends up getting squished down to make room, even though I've set `android:ellipsize="end"` on the `leftTextView`.

Is there a way to make the `leftTextView` have a "truncation priority" that says it should truncate if it would cause other views to not fit? Or on the other side, can I set the `rightTextView` to have a "compression resistance" in order to keep it from being squished to make room for the `leftTextView`? Here's a sample of my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fixedWidthImage"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/leftTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/fixedWidthImage"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fixedWidthImage"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:ellipsize="end" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rightTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/leftTextView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/leftTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Things I've tried:

1. In the `leftTextView`, add a `toStartOf` / `toLeftOf` the `rightTextView` (crashes the app)
2. Instead of aligning the `rightTextView` to the end/right of the `leftTextView`, flip it and align the `leftTextView` to the start/left of the `rightTextView`. This results in the `rightTextView` being anchored to the end of the screen instead of directly to the right of the `leftTextView`. Example of how this ends up looking:

   ```
   |img|leftText                 |rightText||
   |img|leftTextMedium           |rightText||
   |img|leftTextTooLongSoTrunc...|rightText||
   ```
3. Even if I set `android:minWidth="25dp"` just to ensure at least *part* of the `rightTextView` is visible (which I don't want to do because this text length is variable) it still ends up compressing the width to make room for the `leftTextView`.
4. Per [Emanuel Moecklin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/534471)'s answer, I tried wrapping in a `LinearLayout` and setting the weight on the `leftTextView`. The result was visually identical to what I tried in #2.

Comment: In my defense of the duplicate marking, that other question did not have an answer at the time I asked mine. Also, its title is awful which is probably why I did not realize it existed in the first place.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can archive this layout by `TableLayout` and `shrinkColumns` attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Row 1 -->
    <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:shrinkColumns="1">

        <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:text="leftText"/>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:ellipsize="none"
                    android:text="rightText"/>
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>


    <!-- Row 2 -->
    <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:shrinkColumns="1">

        <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:text="leftTextPrettyLongButNotHuge"/>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:ellipsize="none"
                    android:text="rightText"/>
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    <!-- Row 3 -->
    <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:shrinkColumns="1">

        <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:text="leftTextWhichIsIncrediblyLongBlahBlahBlahBlah"/>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:ellipsize="none"
                    android:text="rightText"/>
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Can this be done for vertical layouts? I need the items in the TableRow to be vertically aligned and set android:shrinkColumns="0" to shrink the first view.

Comment: Set `android:shrinkColumns="0"` working fine.

Comment: How can I do this using ConstraintLayout?

Answer (score 6):

Here's what I do:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fixedWidthImage"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_pro" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/leftTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:lines="1"
        android:text="This is a very long text, and now even longer" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rightTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:lines="1"
        android:text="This is also quite long" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The android:layout_weight="1" does the "trick" here. The documentation isn't quite clear on this one though:

> For example, if there are three text fields and two of them declare a
>   weight of 1, while the other is given no weight, the third text field
>   without weight will not grow and will only occupy the area required by
>   its content.

(https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight)

It doesn't elaborate on the case in which there isn't space to fill but not enough space for all views. One interpretation of the mentioned piece of documentation would be that a field without weight (the rightTextView in this case) will occupy the area required by its content while a field with weight (the leftTextView in this case) will "grow" (as in negative growth) and that's exactly what happens.

Comment: While the weight allows for the "negative growth" that you mention, it also expands the field to fill the width when it doesn't need to. This ends up with the `rightTextView` being pinned to the right/end of the parent view. Functionally, it appears the same as it does in #2 of what I tried in the question.

Comment: @Emanuel Moecklin what if I am using a RelativeLayout rather than a LinearLayout?

Comment: @Stonz2 that is what my tests found out as well

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to need to make a custom layout. This works well for the sample I made and it meets all of the requirements you posted above, but you'll need to add a touch more math the code to account for layout_margins and padding.

The basic idea of what's going on here is I subclassed LinearLayout and in the onMeasure pass, I check to make sure that right view has the option to take up as much space as possible. Note that I have to remeasure the right view and not just get the measured width because linearlayout isn't going to give it enough space. Once you have how much room the right view takes up, check to see if the middle view (called leftView...sorry) is taking up more space than you want. If it does, just give it the space that's left over.

Based upon your requirements of it being in a RecyclerView... I know you said you wanted a pure xml solution, but you're going to get better performance if you tackle it in code as xml 1. may be impossible and 2. will require more computations than just doing it yourself directly.

```
public class CustomLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {

private View child0;
private TextView leftView, rightView;
public CustomLinearLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    if (rightView == null) {
        child0 = getChildAt(0);
        leftView = (TextView)getChildAt(1);
        rightView = (TextView) getChildAt(2);
    }

    int spec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getMeasuredWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    rightView.measure(spec, spec);

    int remaining = getMeasuredWidth() - child0.getMeasuredWidth() - rightView.getMeasuredWidth();
    if (leftView.getMeasuredWidth() > remaining) {
        int specW = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(remaining, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        int specH = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(leftView.getMeasuredHeight(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        leftView.measure(specW, specH);
    }
}
```

XML layout

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.joshua.myapplication.MainActivity">

<com.example.joshua.myapplication.CustomLinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#FF0000"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="My Left View With Really Really Long Text That should fill the screen"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="My Right View"
        />
</com.example.joshua.myapplication.CustomLinearLayout>

<com.example.joshua.myapplication.CustomLinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#FF0000"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="My Left View with short text"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="My Right View"
        />
</com.example.joshua.myapplication.CustomLinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer- I gave it a whirl and it works great, but nshmura's approach also works, but is purely in XML and doesn't rely on subclassing.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `android:maxWidth` property to your left textView. So, your leftview will never exceed that limit. and there will be always space for your right view.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fixedWidthImage"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/leftTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/fixedWidthImage"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fixedWidthImage"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxWidth="250dp"
        android:text="This is a Long left Text which never ends and You'll be tired after reading this long stuff.. blah blah... " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rightTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/leftTextView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/leftTextView"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        android:text="Right Text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Preview of layout]

However, limitation with solution is you have to give fixed value in maxWidth property. So, it'll display different look on different screen size. Though, in most cases you'll not face issue.

Also, for displaying long textView in single line `android:ellipsize="marquee"` is good option. As it'll scroll your view horizontal. But don't forget to write this `textView.setSelected(true)` in your code to make it work. [Detail](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3332924/4169014)

Comment: With Android having such a wide disparity of screen sizes (plus portrait and landscape) a fixed width is definitely not a desirable approach.

Comment: I already told that this will work when you know some fixed width size of view. Otherwise you can do it programmatically as @whizzle suggested.